# Migrated question appears same as an newer question; which one is the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates, migration

[If point is zero-dimensional, how can it form a finite one dimensional line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1083841/139123) (originally posted Dec. 27, 2014) was recently migrated here from physics.SE, although it already had answers. But on March 3, 2015, [If point is nothing how come line which made up of set of points has length](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1173396/139123) had already been asked and answered here.

As far as I can see these are the same question with the same possible answers.
Does it make sense to close one as a duplicate of the other? If so, is the duplicate
the question that appeared on this site later (via migration), or the one that
was asked on a later date?

The migrated question already has about two screenfuls of comments from its time on physics.SE, so merely putting a link to the other question in a comment isn't going to be very visible.

Comment: You got your timing wrong, the migrated question was here first. It was migrated on 28$^{\text{th}}$ December and answered the following day. It was edited a couple of hours ago, however, and probably that brought it to attention. But that doesn't matter, which will be closed as a duplicate and whether they should be merged isn't determined by age.

Comment: Apparently I didn't read the "migrated from" banner very carefully, or I would have the question migrated some time ago. My mistake. I noticed the question because it came up on the "top questions" list for activity, so I believe you are right about the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither option is correct.

You should flag either one of them using the free form flag, and ask for the questions to be merged.